# How to use the Reader Monad with (Int -> Int)?

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

I would like to learn, how to use the Reader Monad. Unfortunately only a small amount of example code is available

I would like to create a Reader, where the environment and the retrived values are `Int`. I defined the type like this:

```
type IntRead = Reader Int Int
```

The code I tried is this:

```
addStuff :: Reader Int Int
addStuff = do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)
    return (a+b)
```

I get an error, because `ReaderT` is expected. How to create a function like `addStuff` using the Reader Monad? Where should I provide the environment to this function?

Comment: You must map the function over `ask`: `a <- (*2) <$> ask`

Comment: Thank you, but how it it possible to call `addStuff` with an environment? With this code, I het an error: `addStuff 10`

Comment: It depends on your library. You need a function isomorphic to `Reader a b -> a -> b`. It's usually called `runReader`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert functions to readers and back with these two isomorphisms:

```
reader :: (r -> a) -> Reader r a
runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
```

E.g.

```
addStuff :: Reader Int Int
addStuff = do  
    a <- reader (*2)  
    b <- reader (+10)
    return (a+b)
```

and then you can test your code with `runReader addStuff 5`.

This is OK for learning purposes. For more serious code, you shouldn't use the isomorphisms that much, but instead rely on `ask` or `asks`. E.g.

```
addStuff :: Reader Int Int
addStuff = do  
    x <- ask   -- fetch the implicit Int value
    let a = (*2) x
        b = (+10) x
    return (a+b)
```

or, better

```
addStuff :: Reader Int Int
addStuff = do  
    a <- asks (*2) -- fetch the implicit Int value, and apply the function
    b <- asks (+10)
    return (a+b)
```

or, even better, using applicative style:

```
addStuff :: Reader Int Int
addStuff = (+) <$> asks (*2) <*> asks (+10)
```

The whole point of the reader abstraction is not to think about the underlying function. You can just pretend to have access to a read-only variable, which is accessible through the `ask` primitive.

Usually, only at the very last step you use `runReader` to actually use your monadic reader action.

Comment: Is it possible even better? :O

Comment: Don't worry too much about "clever" code, or shortcuts, for now. If you are  learning, it's more important if you understand the basics, e.g. how it works underneath. It's fine if for a while you will use the two isomorphisms a lot, even if it is not a good style for actual production code.

Comment: `addStuff = liftA2 (+) (* 2) (+ 10)`

Comment: @amalloy But that does not use "the" reader monad, but "the other" reader monad `(->) r` :-P It can be quite confusing to discover that we have two (isomorphic) reader monads in Haskell :)

Comment: Well okay, if you prefer to use the `asks` wrapper you can still do the same thing: `liftA2 (+) (asks (* 2)) (asks (+ 10))`

Comment: @amalloy I was just mentioning it since the "other" version will likely cause several type errors when mixed with previous code using "the" reader monad. In many cases, I actually like the more direct `(->) r` variant.